# Access multiple users inbox/events on facebook / gmail on one browser session- possible from javascript?

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, openid, google-openid

Say I have 3 google accounts and 3 facebook accounts and want to an webapp for viewing the inbox / events for all 3 accounts together. Would that be possible?

I can think of the following options:

1. Using the javascript api's only. (Don't know if it would be possible to have multiple users authenticated at same browse session or switch between the users without reentering passwords?)
2. Merge the inboxes / events on server using some c# api for gmail and facebook. Would those api require a browser session, or would it be possible to store some sort of a authentication token?

Thanks a lot for any suggestion!

Larsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definietly possible to do that with Facebook by using its OAuth authenitcation and corresponding service calls to retrive data. I don't know if gmail supports something like this.

Facebook API/Auth reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/. Note that you'll either have to call services yourself or have one application Id per account you want to pull data for as library provided by Facebook stores user information in cookies named with application Id as prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You need two separate browser sessions, possibly storing cookies in different places (if you want to remember who's logged in) to be logged in to these websites as two users at the same time. Some of them will even free up sessions by examining the IP address; if the same IP has two or more open sessions, all but the youngest are discarded.

The idea is, a computer is used by one person, and that person is supposed to be one user and interact with the web app in one session. That allows for the best overall use of resources. There are very simple ways to enforce this server-side, that are hard to "game" client-side.

Comment: Thanks for explaining about how services might be freeing up sessions by examining ip-address. Good argument for dropping client-side.